# Migrating Cakephp2 Authentication to Cakephp 3

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm moving an app from CakePHP 2 to CakePHP 3.  There is a new hashing algorithm for Cake3.  I'd like the existing users to be able to login to the app using their old passwords and for those passwords to then be updated to the new algorithm.

Unfortunatly, I can't get the correct hash to match up to what is in the database.

```
$person = $this->Auth->identify();
if(!$person){ # maybe they have old sha1 password?
  $oldhash = Security::hash($this->request->data['password'], 
                           'sha1', "oldsalt");                  
  $person = $this->People->find()->where(['password' => $oldhash])->where(['email' =>$this->request->data['email'] ])->first();
  if($person){
    $person->password = Security::hash($this->request->data['password']);
    $this->People->save($person);
  }             
}
```

The user is not found and if i debug the $oldhash out I get a different string than what is stored in the password field for that user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#changing-hashing-algorithms)

Answer (score 5):

## Fallback classes

According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#changing-hashing-algorithms):

> CakePHP provides a clean way to migrate your users’ passwords from one algorithm to another, this is achieved through the FallbackPasswordHasher class. Assuming you are migrating your app from CakePHP 2.x which uses sha1 password hashes, you can configure the AuthComponent as follows:

You will have to create an [Custom Password Hasher](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes) class `src/Auth/`. A Custom Password hasher wil look something like this:

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\AbstractPasswordHasher;

class LegacyPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {

    public function hash($password)
    {
        return sha1($password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword)
    {
        return sha1($password) === $hashedPassword;
    } }
```

and then add it to `passwordhasher` in `authenticate` as `fallback` like this:

```
'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'passwordHasher' => [
                        'className' => 'Fallback',
                        'hashers' => [
                            'Default',
                            'Legacy'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

> The first name appearing in the hashers key indicates which of the classes is the preferred one, but it will fallback to the others in the list if the check was unsuccessful.

`legacy` is the [Custom Password Hasher](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes).

## Updating the password

To update the users' password to the new hash you only have to add this code to your login procedure:

```
if ($this->Auth->authenticationProvider()->needsPasswordRehash()) {
    $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
    $user->password = $this->request->data('password');
    $this->Users->save($user);
}
```

## Documentation

- [More information about Changing hashing Algorithms](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#changing-hashing-algorithms)
- [More information about the Custom Password Hasher](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes)

Comment: This is really good, and explains it better & more explicitly for my case.  Thanks.   I'm still up against the issue that the SHA1 has isn't giving the same hashed version of the password as the previous system, so legacy accounts can't login

Comment: actually.  is that because cake2.x uses something other than sha1?

Comment: oh no wait, it's not actually passing through the default legacy hasher code.

Comment: It the password _is_ passing through the `LegacyPasswordHasher` and the hash is _not_ correct then you have to check whether the salt is causing this (Eg. if the salt is used in the `sha1()` calculation. If the password _is **not**_ passing through the `LegacyPasswordHasher` the issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: i'm passing the salt.  the hash doesn't match.  i'm wondering if cake2 app was really using sha1?

Comment: ok.  got it matching.  not sure what was wrong but definetly sha1

Comment: @Sevvlor Thank you so much to save my life. I was searching what was default algorithm used by `Cakephp 2.x version` and your solution suggest me `sha1`. Thanks again dear :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a CakePHP 2 app using Blowfish. Here's how I made it work with CakePHP 3:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            // ...
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'pass', // make sure you match this with your corresponding login.ctp input name
            ],
            // ...
            'passwordHasher' => [
                'className' => 'Fallback',
                'hashers' => [
                    'Default' => ['hashType' => PASSWORD_BCRYPT],
                ]
            ],
            // ...
        ]
    ],
```

Hope it helps someone googling this issue